# How can i wire-up org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean and org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor?

Tags: hibernate, spring

I wired-up but it did not work as I expected. 
I have set the lazy inialization true between entities abd believe,HibernateInterceptor manages the hibernate session. When I trying to access the object properties, it thorws exception LazyInitializationException.

```
Error messgae : Transaction could not initialize proxy - the owning Session was closed

Stack Trace: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - the owning Session was closed
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.CGLIBLazyInitializer.intercept(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:158)
```

configuration xml

```
<!-- THE HIBERNATE INTERCEPTOR -->
<bean id="hibernateInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="app:sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Start Transaction proxy definition -->

<bean id="app:appTransactionProxy"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean"
    abstract="true">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="app:transactionManager" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
        <prop key="process*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
            <prop key="submit*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="preInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="hibernateInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="postInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="hibernateInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>


<bean id="app:daoTransactionProxy"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean"
    abstract="true">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="app:transactionManager" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="unlock*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
            <prop key="getHead*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
            <prop key="remove*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
            <prop key="create*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
            <prop key="update*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
            <prop key="addTail*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
            <prop key="checkForTimeouts">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
            <prop key="breakOldLocks">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
            <prop key="find*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,readOnly,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
            <prop key="load*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,readOnly,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>
            <prop key="*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,readOnly,
                -Exception,-RuntimeException</prop>

        </props>
    </property>
        <property name="preInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="hibernateInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="postInterceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="hibernateInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="app:transactionManager" name="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">

    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="app:sessionFactory" />
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />
</bean>

    <bean id="app:sessionFactory" name="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="app:dataSource" />

    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>com/app/domain/app.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>com/common/domain/shared.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                ${app.hibernate.dialect}
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="merge">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.IdTransferringMergeEventListener" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<!--Start DATA SOURCE   -->
<bean id="app:dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <!-- Config values-->
</bean>
```

Any input on this ?

Comment: Where is your 'app:transactionManager' ?

Comment: yep, I have added 'app:transactionManager'

Answer (score 0):

*ProxyFactoryBean* allows to apply particular logic on the bean methods calling. *TransactionProxyFactoryBean* IS-A *ProxyFactoryBean* and it allows to apply transaction-management-specific concerns.

*LazyInitializationException* means that you access hibernate proxy outside of active hibernate session context.

I.e. you set transaction infrastructure, asked hibernate to get a proxy for particular entity and tried to access proxy properties after tranasction completion.

Solution is to retrieve the object eagerly or work with it from transactional context only.

Comment: You are correct but i am using org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor as preInterceptors and postInterceptors which should binds a new Hibernate Session to the thread before a method call, closing and removing it afterwards in case of any method outcome. If there already is a pre-bound Session the interceptor simply participates in it.(http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateInterceptor.html) am I getting anything wrong here ?

Comment: Ok, so you retrieve an entity via hibernate and setup HibernateInterceptor to be applied to that entity or what is the target of your HibernateInterceptor?

Comment: A TransactionProxyFactoryBean is a FactoryBean but not a ProxyFactoryBean.